# Split Date into Year and Month in data.table

Tags: r, date, data.table

Given,

```
 set.seed(1234)
 library(data.table)
 dt <- data.table(date=c(201405, 201406, 201501, 201503), x = rnorm(4, 0, 1))
```

return,

```
     date          x
1: 201405 -1.2070657
2: 201406  0.2774292
3: 201501  1.0844412
4: 201503 -2.3456977
```

I want to split date into year and month as follows:

```
   year month          x
1: 2014     5 -1.2070657
2: 2014     6  0.2774292
3: 2015     1  1.0844412
4: 2015     3 -2.3456977
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Isn't this just ```dt[, `:=`(year = substr(date, 1, 4), month = substr(date, 5, 6))]```? Not sure how is this `data.table` specific. You can wrap `as.integer` too there if you like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Converting comment to an answer, you could simply use `substr` combined with the *assignment by reference* semantics. You can wrap it up into `as.integer` if you prefer it not to return a string

```
dt[, `:=`(year = substr(date, 1L, 4L), month = substr(date, 5L, 6L))]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this->

```
 dt$month=as.integer(substr(dt$date,5,6))  
 dt$year=substr(dt$date,1,4)    
 dt  
 date               x month year  
 1: 201405 -1.2070657     5 2014  
 2: 201406  0.2774292     6 2014  
 3: 201501  1.0844412     1 2015  
 4: 201503 -2.3456977     3 2015
```